Why I am getting two different medians
let's say we have: $10, 12, 15, 10, 10, 12$
sorted: $10,10,10,12,12,15$
this way is clear that the median is $\frac{10+12}{2} = 11$
however, I was told that I could find the median using this table


Pick the first row whose accumulated frequency is greater than or equal to the target position. If the target position exactly matches the accumulated frequency, average the values of this row and the following row to get the median, else the value of this row is the median.

$\frac{6+1}{2} = 3.5$ now look at a value with that Accumulated frequency  then look at the number in that row = 12
why I don't get the same median?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You've found an interesting edge case that disproves poorly written explanations of how to find the median from a table.
The accumulated frequency tells you the last position to have that value: the 3rd number is the last 10; the 5th number is the last 12; the 6th number is the last 15.
When we are looking for a position, then, we look for the first accumulated frequency to exceed that position and that corresponds to the value of interest.
However, in the slogan $(n+1)/2$, we don't always get an ordinal position like 3rd or 4th. Sometimes we get $3.5$, which means to us "the midpoint of the 3rd and 4th value".
Using the accumulated frequency, the 3rd value is 10, the 4th value is 12 and so the midpoint is 11.
You can generalise this to other quantiles like quartiles or percentiles, in which case you get slogans like $(n+1)/100$ and have to think through what the $3.04$th position could mean (it's 4% of the way into the interval between the 3rd and 4th values).
The median can be defined differently for even, finite data sets. In probability, you might say any $x\in (10,12)$ is "a median" because half of the data is below it and half is above it. In statistics, for large data often $n/2$ is used rather than $(n+1)/2$, under the assumption that the difference is negligible in practical applications.

@samsamradas This is what makes it statistics rather than probability - anything goes. If you are studying a course they may have a convention that is followed, but in general there's no definition of "large".

do you think pos = $\frac{n}{2}$ and the table algorithm for any even sorted dataset will get the same result as taking the mean of the middle values?

@samsamradas No, $(n+1)/2$ is the exact median and $n/2$ has no guarantee of exactness or even closeness.
